# Load HTML dependancy from serialised file using WebKit

Tags: javascript, html, serialization, webkit, html-rendering

I am trying to render an HTML page using WebKit framework. The HTML is having external dependancy like, images and java scripts. Due to security reasons, I need to decode and serialise all the HTML related files (i.e. HTML, GIF, JS etc files). To load the HTML in to the container, I should decode and de-serialise files as and when required. The modules to encode and decode, serialise and de-serialise are ready with me. But, I am unable to understand where to plug them in in to the webkit frame work so that the complete HTML can get loaded.
For example, say in the main.html, script.js and image.gif have been embedded and I have serialised the three files in to a file called "file_one". Now when my application starts I am extracting the main.html and loading it, but the script.js and image.gif also need to be loaded, but how do I know or which event of the webkit framework will tell me that the container is now searching for other dependancies.

Thanks in advance :-)